# Navbar moves behind my text, animations, cards etc

Tags: jquery, html, css

Description: When you scroll down the black navbar appears but when you further scroll down towards carousel you will see that the navbar moves behind it. This is happening not only for carousel but to other texts, cards etc in my site. The black navbar makes the problem. Below is the demo of that problem

```js
$('.navTrigger').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    console.log("Clicked menu");
    $("#mainListDiv").toggleClass("show_list");
    $("#mainListDiv").fadeIn();

});
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-size: 10px;
}
/*-- Inspiration taken from abdo steif -->
/* --> https://codepen.io/abdosteif/pen/bRoyMb?editors=1100*/

/* Navbar section */

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav div.logo {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 3rem;
}

.nav div.logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.nav div.logo a:hover {
    color: #00E676;
}

.nav div.main_list {
    height: 65px;
    float: right;
}

.nav div.main_list ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li {
    width: auto;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 3rem;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li a:hover {
    color: #00E676;
}


/* Home section */
.navTrigger {
    display: none;
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.home {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(blue-sky-blur-clear-sky-color-281260.jpg);
    background-position: center top;
    background-size:cover;

}

/* Media query section */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .navTrigger {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav div.logo {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .nav div.main_list {
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nav div.show_list {
        height: auto;
        display: none;
    }
    .nav div.main_list ul {
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        /*same background color of navbar*/
        background-position: center top;
    }
    .nav div.main_list ul li {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .nav div.main_list ul li a {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 3rem;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .nav div.media_button {
        display: block;
    }
}


/* Animation */
/* Inspiration taken from Dicson https://codemyui.com/simple-hamburger-menu-x-mark-animation/ */

.navTrigger {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.navTrigger i {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
}

.navTrigger i:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation: outT 0.8s backwards;
    animation: outT 0.8s backwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

.navTrigger i:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 5px 0;
    -webkit-animation: outM 0.8s backwards;
    animation: outM 0.8s backwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

.navTrigger i:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation: outBtm 0.8s backwards;
    animation: outBtm 0.8s backwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
    animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
}

.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation: inM 0.8s forwards;
    animation: inM 0.8s forwards;
}

.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation: inBtm 0.8s forwards;
    animation: inBtm 0.8s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes inM {
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}

@keyframes inM {
    50% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes outM {
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}

@keyframes outM {
    50% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes inT {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
    }
}

@keyframes inT {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes outT {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
    }
}

@keyframes outT {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes inBtm {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
    }
}

@keyframes inBtm {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes outBtm {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
    }
}

@keyframes outBtm {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
    }
}

.affix {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #111;
}






.myH2 {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 4rem;
}
.myP {
    text-align: justify;
    padding-left:15%;
    padding-right:15%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
@media all and (max-width:700px){
    .myP {
        padding:2%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link href="bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="CHECK.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="CHECK.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">Your Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="mainListDiv" class="main_list">
            <ul class="navlinks">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <span class="navTrigger">
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
            </span>
    </div>
</nav>

<section class="home">

</section>
<div style="height: 1000px">
    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

        </ul>

        <!-- The slideshow -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="headed-down-1400175.jpg">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1 class="display-2 animated bounceInRight" style="text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;animation-delay: 0.5s;">Text</h1>
                    <h3>Text</h3>
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary>More info</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

<!-- Function used to shrink nav bar removing paddings and adding black background -->
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('.nav').addClass('affix');
            console.log("OK");
        } else {
            $('.nav').removeClass('affix');
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `z-index:999` property to `.nav` class which will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property in your nav css

```
z-index: 1;
```

then it will appear above the content

So your nav css becomes

```
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```